# SQL Server - how to backup whole database except for data inside some tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, backup, smo

I need to backup a database but leave some tables empty (not to backup their records). The scheme should stay the same, and the rest of the tables should stay populated.

Is there a way to do so using .NET SMO or command line (batch is just as good)?

For what it's worth - the tables with the unwanted data have no relationships with other tables.

I know I can copy the database to a temp database and delete all records from the relevant tables, but this is not the solution I'm looking for.

TIA.

Comment: As a fudge, you could play around with multiple schemas and file group backups.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929327/sql-server-2005-restore-one-schema-only

Comment: Only way I see would be to: **(1)** generate scripts (structure + data) for those tables you're OK with having the data -> store that into one `.sql` file, and then **(2)** generate scripts (structure only) for those tables you don't want any data for and store that into a second `.sql` file and then execute these two SQL files on your target database

Comment: How can I generate a data script? S